# TextView ClickableSpan styling for pressed state

Tags: android, textview

I am subclassing ClickableSpan to customize the text style for links in my TextView.

```
private static class LinkSpan extends ClickableSpan {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
         // code...
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        ds.setTypeface(Typeface.create(ds.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD));
        ds.setColor(0xff336699);
    }
}
```

I want to change the style when it's in a pressed state, or a user touches the link. (like `a:hover` in css) but I can't figure out a way to get the current state in `updateDrawState`.

Is there any way to handle this? If I can't change text style, I want to be able to change the background color at least.

**EDIT** as pointed by a comment, you can find the answer at [Change the text color of a single ClickableSpan when pressed without affecting other ClickableSpans in the same TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856105/change-the-text-color-of-a-single-clickablespan-when-pressed-without-affecting-o/20905824#20905824)

Comment: Did you find the answer? How did you end up doing this?

Comment: For whoever this may help in the future, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20905824/1646326

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For changing background color I did

```
testTextView.setHighlightColor(Color.BLUE);
```

on the TextView.

But having the chance to change the text color would be better to me.

Comment: This was not what I asked, but I accepted this answer since it's the only answer. The real solution is at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20905824/1646326

Comment: Next time don't be shy to post the link in an actual answer and mark that as correct. It will help others by making the answer more visible.

Comment: @dasony if this is not the answer the there is no point in marking it as such. I guess it would be more helpful for you to edit your question to point people to that link, in case you don't want to post your own link answer.