# ClickableSpan with custom background Color State List (pressed state)

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView which contains a clickable text followed by a normal text followed by a clickable text. I want to set a custom pressed color to the clickable texts and not to the whole TextView. Right now I can remove the underline, change the text by subclassing ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446079/textview-clickablespan-styling-for-pressed-state)) the ClickableSpan, but unable to set the pressed state color.
Kindly suggest.