# Android: Why multiple links in TextView are highlighted?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have textview in which multiple links are shown, the text is dynamic.
I have added following to textview

```
android:autoLink="all"
android:textColorLink="@color/selector_autolink_textcolor"
```

This makes all links in textview show a different color and show click color, but on click of textview all the links in textview show selected color, this confuses the user as he cannot identify what he's clicking.
How can I only highlight/show press-state of a single link when pressed.

Comment: can you post  screenshot of the clicks

Comment: @Sushrita sorry cannot do that, did you get what I mean to say ?

Answer (score 1):

I have two approaches for you to solve this problem.

First Approach:- This one is quite simple. You can use different TextView to display hyperlinks and display the links. On clicking them you can get different selector color

Second Approach:- Use can use Spannable concept in Android to achieve this. Break the string into different part to show different hyper links. You can achieve the different color slector based upon user click. You can follow this example more from here (see try Spannable part) [Change the text color of a single ClickableSpan when pressed without affecting other ClickableSpans in the same TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856105/change-the-text-color-of-a-single-clickablespan-when-pressed-without-affecting-o)

Comment: 1st approach is not possible as the text is dynamic and I dont want to process all text for multiple textviews, for 2nd approach I'll post shortly if that works.
Thanks

Comment: Approach 2 also doesnt work, in my case autolink is used, i'll have to set spans if I want to use that solution

Comment: Paste me what have you tried ? Let me see then what can be done for you