# How to use ClickableSpan, but ignore clicks from the TextView

Tags: android

The following code shows how I'm applying a pressed state using a custom ClickableSpan and selector. However, the pressed state is applied whenever I press anywhere on the TextView, not just the ClickableSpan. How do I stop this?

**Note: it does not call** `onClick`**, but does apply** `state_pressed` **from the selector. I want it to do neither.**

*MyView.java*

```
SpannableString spanned = new SpannableString("click here");
spannable.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spanned);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

*MyClickableSpan.java*

```
public abstract class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan {

    @Override
    public abstract void onClick(View view);

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);
    }
}
```

*the TextView*

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorLink="@color/my_selector" />
```

*my_selector.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/my_color_pressed" />
    <item android:color="@color/my_color" />
</selector>
```

---

**Edit note: Added TextView code**

Comment: show the code where you set your ClickableSpan into TextView

Comment: Have you tried my solution ?

Comment: @Fifer Sheep, may be u are searching for this solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856105/change-the-text-color-of-a-single-clickablespan-when-pressed-without-affecting-o

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5184835/5392118) out. This may solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Next example works as you're expecting:

```
    Spannable span = SpannableStringBuilder.valueOf("Hello clickable span!");
    span.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(), 6, 15, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    mTextView.setText(span);
    mTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Now span applied:
[image]

Here's MyClickableSpan() that's only show Snackbar to indicate that "click" is handled:

```
class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        Snackbar.make(getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Click on span!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

We've got:

1. Click/tap outside the "spanned" text will do nothing
2. Click/tap on "spanned" part of text will show Snackbar

[image]

That's it. Please let me know if you need any additional info.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set MovementMethod to the TextView which has the Span.

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I should have added the TextView code I already have, as I already set a movement method. I have added this code now.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer below code I have tested it.

```
 String s = "This is custom string click Here";
    SpannableString spanned = new SpannableString(s);
    spanned.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            Log.i("main", "Link clicked");
        }
    }, s.length() - 10, s.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(spanned);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

TextView

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@drawable/my_selector"
    android:textColorLink="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

[You can use tutorial here](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have define

```
 android:textColor="@android:color/white"
```

instead of this you have to define your selector like below

```
 android:textColor="@drawable/my_selector"
```

rest of code is as it is you have to changed only one line that `android:textColor="@drawable/my_selector"` that i explain above.

Comment: The `textColor` attribute is overridden by the `textColorLink` attribute - so this doesn't help me. The non-link text color is fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this way:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
Spannable span = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable("test link span");
span.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("main", "Link clicked");
        Toast.makeText(HomeScreenActivity.this, "link clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } }, 5, 9, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

   // set the "test " spannable.
      span.setSpan(cs, 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

   // set the " span" spannable
      span.setSpan(cs, 6, span.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textView.setText(span);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: In the line `span.setSpan(cs, 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);`, what is `cs`?

Comment: @Fifer Sheep, it is the character string. Means your string on which you want to set span.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I still see the pressed state on the link when I tap the other parts of the TextView.